# c++ sleep(0) loop behaviour

Tags: c++, linux, time, sleep

My question concerns the running time of a loop of sleep(0) operations and the number of parameters passed as arguments. Consider the following snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
      int i;
  int N = 10000000000;
  if(argc > 2)
    N = std::atoi(argv[1]);
  clock_t startTime = clock();
  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    sleep(0);
  double res = double( clock() - startTime ) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  std::cout << res << std::flush;
  return 0;
}
```

After compiling with `c++`, when I run this

```
./a.out
```

or this (with any integer in lieu of N)

```
./a.out N
```

I consistently get an execution time between 5e-6 and 9e-6 independently of the number of iterations entered as a parameter

When I add second (unused) parameter

```
./a.out N 0
```

I get an execution time that is roughly 7e-6 up to 1000 iterations. Time then increases linearly up to ~36 for 1e10 iterations. After that, running time plateaus.

The execution time for the second case relative to N (number of iterations of the for loop) is illustrated in the following graph.

[image: Time to execute N sleep(0) operations]

Note 1: if I modify the code to use that extra parameter, my execution time is the (roughly) same as when I don't use the value of `argv[2]`, so the running time seems to be dependent on the fact that an extra argument was passed in the command line, not on whether that extra argument is useful or not.

Note 2: if I pass a third (and fourth, and fifth) argument in the command line,  the execution time is the same as when I pass two arguments to the function.

What explains this behavior? Why are the execution times different in both cases? Why does the execution time of the second case increase before saturating?

Comment: Is your `int` type big enough for this?

Comment: A little bit of debugging would have led you to the answer that EJP provides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (argc > 2)
    N = atoi(argv[1]);
```

This means that the first argument is ignored unless you supply two or more arguments. It should be:

```
if (argc > 1)
    N = atoi(argv[1]);
```